# Procedure is throwing compile time error oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

New for oracle, Facing compile time error while making procedure , so could anybody help me to rectify that error.

Code Snippet:

```
Create or replace Procedure prc_DropUselessTables(userID number:=0)
as
ncount number:=0;
Begin

Select count(*) from User_Tables where table_name='DummyTable';

if(ncount>0) then

Drop table DummyTable;----Error Line

end if;

end prc_DropUselessTables;
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't have error, what's your error and how you are executing it?

Comment: You need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to run DDL inside a procedure. When asking a question always show what error you are getting. I believe you have got the error `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DROP" when expecting....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly run DDL inside a procedure. You need to use [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prc_DropUselessTables (userID NUMBER := 0)
AS
   ncount   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO NCOUNT
     FROM User_Tables
    WHERE table_name = 'DummyTable';

   IF (ncount > 0)
   THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Drop table DummyTable';
   END IF;
END prc_DropUselessTables;
```

Comment: thanks Nitish for your reply,Execute statement has limitations for 30 characters so how to cater that?

Comment: There is no 30 character limitation for `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Have a look at this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm)